# Interfacing with a custom camera in Linux on the beaglebone

Tags: linux, camera, driver

I need some pointers to help me get a camera (OV7670) working on a beaglebone running debian.

Using the camera capes as a guide, I have connected the camera to the GPMC pins on the beagleboard and the I2C pins. However I am a bit stumped to what I need to do in software to get Linux to recognize it as a camera and be able to use it to read a frame from the GPMC.

From the readings I have done, it seems like I need to load a kernel module. I found that there is a OV7670 C driver file in the kernel source. What kind of modifications (if any) would I need to do?

I am also open to any suggested readings and tutorials that would help me.

Comment: Have you found any tutorial or reading? Please guide as I need help too. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status of the C driver for AM335X devices:
*"/arch/arm/configs/am335x_evm_defconfig: # CONFIG_VIDEO_OV7670 is not set"*
Looks like you'll need to compile your own kernel with OV7670 enabled, or...

As an alternative, you could write your own simple driver using one of the bones two on-board programmable real-time units (PRUs). You'll need to become familiar with assembly but that shouldn't take anymore than 2-3hrs of dedicated reading and you only need to do it once. The PRUs run on a 200MHz clock so every instruction is 5ns - more than enough time to generate a clock for the OV7670 and OV5642. (I've created a collection of examples on GitHub for the PRU: https://github.com/TekuConcept/PRU_Demo - currently working on a driver for three OV5642 cameras on one bone for the AUVSI-robonation annual competition)

Another alternative is the [LogiBone](http://valentfx.com/logi-bone/) which is an FPGA cape for the bone. You may need to become familiar with Verilog for this one; nevertheless the developers I talked with said they have an add-on available for OmniVision cameras and are working on implementing various OpenCV software features.

As far as reading, there is nothing better than a well-documented datasheet!

- http://www.voti.nl/docs/OV7670.pdf
- http://www.phytec.com/wiki/images/7/72/AM335x_techincal_reference_manual.pdf
- http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU_Assembly_Instructions
- "Verilog for Digital Design" by Frank & Roman